# How to use Asyncio with while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

My code creates an order with an API whenever a product_id is entered. It then checks, in timed interval loops, if the order was created successfully. I'm definitely not using asyncio right and was hoping if someone could provide a tip or if even asyncio is the right tool for the job?

I checked the documentation and examples online but find it difficult to understand, most likely because I'm still learning how to code (beginner programmer w/ Python 3.7.1)

```
import asyncio
import requests
import time


#creates order when a product id is entered
async def create_order(product_id):
        url = "https://api.url.com/"
    payload = """{\r\n    \"any_other_field\": [\"any value\"]\r\n  }\r\n}"""       
    headers = {
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    result = response.json()
    request_id = result['request_id']
    result = asyncio.ensure_future(check_orderloop('request_id'))
    return result


#loops and check the status of the order.
async def check_orderloop(request_id):
    print("checking loop: " + request_id)   
    result = check_order(request_id)
    while result["code"] == "processing request":
        while time.time() % 120 == 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(120)
            result = check_order(request_id)
            print('check_orderloop: ' + result["code"])
            if result["code"] != "processing request":
                if result["code"] == "order_status":
                    return result
                else:
                    return result


#checks the status of the order with request_id         
async def check_order(request_id):
    print("checking order id: " + request_id)
    url = "https://api.url.com/" + request_id

    headers = {
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    result = response.json()
    return result


asyncio.run(create_order('product_id'))
```

W/o asyncio, it can only create+check for one order at a time. I would like the code to be able to create+check for many different orders simultaneously and asynchronously.

When I test by trying two different product ids, it gave the following and doesn't complete the functions.

```
<coroutine object create_order at 0x7f657b4d6448>
>create_order('ID1234ABCD')
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'create_order' was never awaited
<coroutine object create_order at 0x7f657b4d6748>
```

Comment: You definitely don't want to use sync `requests` library in async code, use `aiohttp` instead. It even has almost the same API!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad to use blocking `requests` library in asynchronous code. Your program will wait for each request to finish and will not do anything meantime. You can use [async `aiohttp` library](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request) instead.

You can't just call `async` function and expect it to be executed, it will just return you a `coroutine` object. You have to add this coroutine to event loop by `asyncio.run()`, how you did in the code:

```
>>> asyncio.run(create_order('ID1234ABCD'))
```

Or if you want to run multiple coroutines in the same time:

```
>>> asyncio.run(
    asyncio.wait([
        create_order('ID1234ABCD'),
        create_order('ID1234ABCD')
    ])
)
```

Also if you want to test your `async` functions from REPL comfortably, you can use [IPython](https://ipython.org/install.html), it can run async functions right from REPL (only for versions newer than 7.0).

Install:

```
pip3 install ipython
```

Run:

```
ipython
```

And now you can await your async function:

```
In [1]: await create_order('ID1234ABCD')
```